# How do I add a BitMap to ListView using SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, hashmap, simpleadapter

This is what I've tried :

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("tit", "Title : " + title[i]);
    hm.put("init","Initial Price : " + cur_price[i]);
    hm.put("cur","Current Price  : " + init_price[i]);
    hm.put("img", bitmap[i].toString() );
    aList.add(hm); //I'm getting an error here
}

// Keys used in Hashmap
String[] from = { "tit","init","cur","img"};

// Ids of views in listview_layout
int[] to = { R.id.tit,R.id.init,R.id.cur,R.id.img};


SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I think to assign an imageview with Bitmap, one might use something like :

```
 ImageView logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

1) But How can I do the same in SimpleAdapter?

2) Moreover, why is that I'm getting an error at HashMap's add() method?

Comment: HashMap and SimpleAdapter does not seem to fit for your solutions

Comment: Oh! What do you recommend then pl ?

Comment: I would describe the model for the list item and implemented an adapter for it

Comment: Which type of Adapter?

Comment: `BaseAdapter`. post your logs pls.